# Best Practice to catch Hibernate/JPA/Session unique key duplicate exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

Am not sure my title is explicit enough. here is what i mean.I'm developing a web application using `spring 3.0.5 + hibernate 3.6.1.RELEASE`  with `JPA annotation` using `sessionFactory`.The application allows users to signup using `username`, `email` and `password`.

users can log in using `(username or email)` and `password`. I'm trying to find a reliable way to tell there is a unique contraint exception expressed as

> `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry 'myusername' for key 'USERNAME'` or `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update`

if i could get a specific exception i could notify the user that his username or email is already taken.

What comes to my mind is to do a select before to check but then that doesn't sound right to me.Any other solution ? what's the best practice?

Thanks for reading this

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173088/duplicate-key-issue-with-hibernate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually best practice would be to check if a user with that username/email address already exists when creating a new user. If it does then return something to indicate a failure, otherwise create the user.

Generally you shouldn't rely on database constraints for enforcing business rules.

Comment: We have some race condition where the client makes multiple user creation requests at the same time. We do check if the user exists, but that obviously is not enough in a race condition. We are trying to discipline the client, but we would like to return an appropriate message as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's okay to do the select to check.

In general, if you're creating unique IDs, they should be unique, so a uniqueness violation is an exceptional error condition, and should be handled by catching the exception.

But here, you're letting users supply the hopefully-unique key. You just can't assume that these really will be non-unique. So, you should check whether the username is taken before trying to create the user object.

Comment: Hi thanks, i could have marked your answer as accepted response but it seems you were 2 min late @milkplusvellocet as first. so +1 ;)

Comment: No problem! Hopefully it's reassuring that you had two answers saying the same thing.